# How can I add multiple inputs and randomize it for other objects using it?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

In this project there are multiple tv screens which I want to project different videos on different ones and It takes time to have multiple shaders for all of them. So I want to know if there is a way to choose all of the videos and randomize them for the screens, so that we have different tv screens screening different videos.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Object Info** Node to get a random value per object. Using this random number you can decide what image to display.

Here's one way to do it

[image: Shader]